# Почему не находит файл?

Tags: java, pdf

Файл bus.pdf находится в той же директории что класс Test.java.
Выдает такую ошибку

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: us.pdf (Синтаксическая ошибка в имени файла, имени папки или метке тома)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:797)
    at com.nw.pdf.Test.main(Test.java:16)

import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String string = null;

        try{
            File file = new File("\bus.pdf");
            PDDocument pdDocument = PDDocument.load(file);  
        }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        };

    }

}
```

Comment: Потому, что пути начинающегося с символа `\` быть не может.

Comment: Если у тебя pdf-файл лежит там же, где и исходник, то воспользуйся методом [getResourceAsStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)). Примерно так `PDDocument pdDocument=PDDocument.load(Test.class.getResourceAsStream('bus.pdf'));`

Comment: Попробовал - выдает NullPointerException

Answer (score 1):

Прописал путь так
File file = new File("C:/Users/Николай/workspace1/PDFLayoutTextStripper1/src/com/nw/pdf/bus.pdf");

Добавил баночку commons-logging

Comment: В вопрос можно внести изменения с помощью кнопки «править» под ним. Не публикуйте новые вопросы как ответы. И да, если появляются новые ошибки, то с ними сначала надо бы поработать (ввести в поиск, попробовать разобраться в причинах).

Comment: Добавил баночку commons-logging и ошибок больше нет. Спасибо.

Comment: Не за что. Поздравляю! :) Тогда уже доработайте ответ, через 48 часов его можно будет принять